# Cannot run Automake , error : Thread/Queue.pm did not return a true value at /usr/bin/automake line 55

Tags: makefile, ide, autotools, gnome

I recently installed gnome-builder and instantiated a project. I cannot build it. The build output of the Project is

```
home/aswinmohanme/Projects/GtkOfficial/autogen.sh
Automake/Config.pm did not return a true value at /usr/bin/aclocal line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/aclocal line 37.
```

How do I fix this.

`automake --version
        Same Error as the Question
        1.15
    perl --version
        v5.24.1`

P.S : Comment what more should I post.

Comment: automake version, perl version, Makefile.am. And if the Automake/Config.pm module contains a "1;"

Comment: @arved sorry for the delay, got hung up. So what do I do Next.

Comment: Question title, body, and question asked on IRC don't match. Is it Automake/Config.pm or Thread/Queue.pm that show up in which error? Can you run 'perldoc -lm Thread::Queue'?

Comment: Whenever I run automake from anywhere, Thread::Queue error is thrown. And here is the output of `perldoc` `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Thread/Queue.pm`